# Clarification on a Graph Theory proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand this following proof:

> If $G = <V, E> $ where $\vert V\vert = v$ and $\vert E\vert = e$ and G
>   is simple, prove that $2e \le V^2-V$

In the example I'm following, the author takes the example of this graph:

[image]

The author says that, if this was our graph then the number of edges would be equal to $3 \choose 2$. Which is equal to 3, and I don't understand that.

Since our graph is simple, in this example, the max number of edges can only be equal to 1. No?

I need clarification on exactly why the number of edges is equal to $3 \choose 2$ in this example or, in general, $V \choose 2$.

From there, if I have $V \choose 2$ it is easy for me to "convert" it to $\dfrac{V(V-1)}{2}$, so I don't need help on this part.

Thanks.

Comment: Given $v$ vertices, how many edges can there be between them at most? Note that this amounts to counting the number of unordered pairs of vertices.

Comment: @Michael It seems you arent sure of what a simple graph is. I would look this up and read it more carefully. In the graph in the picture, if it is simple then indeed the maximum number of edges is $3 = \binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: Well, if I have 4 vertices for example, I can only have 2 edges. If I have 6, I can only have 3. How can this help me?

Comment: You are correct!!! I though that a simple graph was a graph where one vertice can only have one and only one edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices. Notice that each edge is simply a unique pair $(v_i,v_j)$ of vertices. How many distinct pairs of vertices like this are there where we consider $(v_i,v_j) = (v_j,v_i)$? The most basic result in counting is that this is just $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$. Thus, $e \leq \frac{n^2-n}{2}$ and so $2e \leq n^2 - n$ as desired.